# Open xxx.out file with doubleclick?

Tags: command-line, doubleclick

This is my first post so please don't mind my mistakes.

I have searched on google for some time but can't seem to find the answer to my question.

After I wrote some code in c language with *gedit*, I made a executable program with terminal using `cc xxx.c` and ran it with `./a.out`, its works just fine but why cant I run it by double clicking on its icon. When I double click or choose *run* from right click context menu nothing happens.

So my question is "**Is it possible to run 'xxx.out' file with double click like other apps in Ubuntu?**"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe. It's probably a bad idea, but try something like this (may not be 100% correct, you may have to figure a few things out):

1. Check value of `mimetype a.out`. It's probably `application/x-executable`. If there's no value, this won't work.
2. edit the `defaults.list` file in either `/usr/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/applications` (possibly one under local should be called `mimeapps.list`), adding an entry mapping the mime type to some .desktop file.
3. Create the .desktop file, Giving it an exec line which does what you want (say, open an xterm and run the program).
4. Rebuild the mime cache with `update-desktop-database`.

If you did it correctly, `xdg-open a.out` in the terminal will do whatever you want to have happen when you double-click the file.

Me, I'd stick to the terminal.

Comment: Hi first of all thank you for your answer.
I opened deafults.list on gedit but now I have no idea what do next. Would you please elaborate step 2. I would like it to open in terminal by clicking.  I am just a beginner in ubuntu so details will be appreciated.

Comment: `ls /usr/share/applications`. You see a bunch of .desktop files. defaults.list has a bunch lines of the form `<mime-type>=<name.desktop>`. Each line maps a mime type to a recipe for running files of that type. You're going to create your own .desktop file, and add a line mapping `application/x-executable` to that file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to run it in a terminal then the chances are, it's running just fine when you double click it.  However, since your program probably doesn't create it's own window, the output is likely just not being displayed.

Try the following:

1. Create a program that writes output to a file in tmp
2. Run the program from a terminal to see that it does create the file
3. Delete the file it created
4. Check that the file no longer exists
5. Double click the program to run it
6. See if it created the file

If you see a file created after double clicking, then your application did run.

If your program doesn't create a gui of it's own, you may be able to make a shortcut for it and tell that shortcut to the run the command in a terminal.  Which, in retrospect, is exactly the process that user3113723 is describing...

Comment: You are right Stephen. I created a program to delete a certain file and when I double click on that xx.out file it deletes the file I want. So the program is working.  I will try the option below ? By the way I would have voted your answer useful but I only have 6rep :(.